# Can I use "getpwuid" from kernel code in LKM in c code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I would like to a lib that is equivalent to getpwuid() from LKM module which is in kernel space to get "passwd" structure.
Will you advice me how I can do it to get the "passwd" structure from kernel space not from user space?
Thank you.
//DAUM

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely unlikely you have any valid reason to do this. You will have to elaborate.

In short, the setup can be quite complicated and e.g. involve querying databases on different machines. For /joke/ purposes one could implement that by having a userspace helper for the kernel.

Comment: I would like to this because my LKM from kernel space needs to check what is the user name of the sys_call caller.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Why do you need the name.

Comment: I need the name because our proprietary security function in LKM needs to know the account name so as to control privilege. That is, the proprietary security policy file has the account name for privilege control.

Comment: But why does it contain user names. Why it cannot translate them into uids prior to feeding the policy into the kernel? This is an extremely bad design. As noted earlier, if really needed, you can just spawn a userspace helper and talk with it over a netlink socket, device fd or whatever.